# How to place text on the right side of the image?

Tags: html, css, image, layout, slider

I am Trying To place My text "div" on the blank space of my slider div.

[image: My Work So Far]

The text needs to be placed on the right side of the image. 2 more text div blocks need to be placed under the 1st div too! So I dunno how to bring the div to the right of the slider div and place future divs below that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `text div` using `position`

```
[selector] {
    position: absolute;
    right : 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot !! it Actually Worked Fr Me ! Appreciating The Help !!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="imgWrap clearfix">
    <div class="Slider_img">put img source here</div>
    <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.clearfix 
{
    zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.Slider_img {
    float:left;
    width:70%; 
}
.content{
    float:right;
    width:30%;
}
```